# File losing type between OnGet and OnPost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a file upload website I made using ASP.NET, when on the "details" page if you click edit it takes you to a page (passing the ID) and allows you to edit the comments field.

In the screenshot below is me debugging the OnGet for the page which goes into the context and gets all the info for that file:

[image: OnGet]

As you can see FileType is populated and it brings through the number and the current comment for that file.

[image: Comment Change]

When a change is made and you press save, as soon as you go into the OnPost, filetype is null and I don't know where its losing it?

[image: OnPost]

I've included both frontend and backend code below: any help appreciated.

back end:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FarmersPortal.Data;
using File = FarmersPortal.Data.File;
using FarmersPortal.Enums;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using FarmersPortal.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace FarmersPortal.Pages.Admin
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext _context;

        public EditModel(FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public File File { get; set; }= default!;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Files == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var file =  await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (file == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            File = file;
           ViewData["VendorId"] = new SelectList(_context.Vendors, "Id", "Id");
            return Page();
        }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(File File, int? id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //return Page();
            }
            
            _context.Attach(File).Property(x => x.Comments).IsModified = true;

            //var file2 = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            //File = file2;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (File.FileType == "Purchase Order")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/PurchaseOrders");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Remittance")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Remittance");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Haulage Self Bill")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/HaulageSelfBill");
            }
            else if (File.FileType == "Growers Return")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/GrowersReturn");
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }

        private bool FileExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Files.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

front end:

```
@page
@model FarmersPortal.Pages.Admin.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('../hero-range-1.jpg');
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        /*        background-color: white;*/
    }
</style>
<h1 style="color:white">Edit</h1>

<h4 style="color:white">File</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-white"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="File.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="File.Number" class="control-label" style="color:white"></label>
                <input asp-for="File.Number" class="form-control" readonly/>
                <span asp-validation-for="File.Number" class="text-white"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="File.Comments" class="control-label" style="color:white"></label>
                <input asp-for="File.Comments" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="File.Comments" class="text-white"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model.File?.Id" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @if (Model.File.FileType == "Purchase Order")
    {
        <a asp-page="/PurchaseOrders">Back to List</a>
    }
    @if (Model.File.FileType == "Remittance")
    {
        <a asp-page="/Remittance">Back to List</a>
    }
    @if (Model.File.FileType == "Haulage Self Bill")
    {
        <a asp-page="/HaulageSelfBill">Back to List</a>
    }
    @if (Model.File.FileType == "Growers Return")
    {
        <a asp-page="/GrowersReturn">Back to List</a>
    }
    | <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-Id="@Model.File.Id">Back to details</a>
    
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: A new instance of your PageModel is created for every action (get and post), you will need to reload from the db every action. I would recommend creating a DTO for your form, load your `file` then update the properties on said file. Don't bind File to your form directly.

Comment: @mxmissile Ah okay thank you. Could you advise how to do this or point me in the direction of an article/tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my back end code to reflect the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FarmersPortal.Data;
using File = FarmersPortal.Data.File;
using FarmersPortal.Enums;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using FarmersPortal.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace FarmersPortal.Pages.Admin
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext _context;

        public EditModel(FarmersPortal.Data.filedbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public File File { get; set; }= default!;
        [BindProperty]
        public File File2 { get; set; } = default!;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Files == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var file =  await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (file == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            File = file;
           ViewData["VendorId"] = new SelectList(_context.Vendors, "Id", "Id");
            return Page();
        }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(File File, int? id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //return Page();
            }

            var file2 = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            file2.Comments = File.Comments;
            File2 = file2;

            _context.Attach(File2).Property(x => x.Comments).IsModified = true;

            //var file2 = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            //File = file2;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (File2.FileType == "Purchase Order")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/PurchaseOrders");
            }
            else if (File2.FileType == "Remittance")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Remittance");
            }
            else if (File2.FileType == "Haulage Self Bill")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/HaulageSelfBill");
            }
            else if (File2.FileType == "Grower Returns")
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/GrowersReturn");
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }

        private bool FileExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Files.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```